# "change" event lags one step behind javascript

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I am trying to make a very simple webpage that takes an input file and displays the contents in the console. When I try to use it, it sort of works, but is always one step behind. For example,

1) Upload "1.txt" -> Console prints ""

2) Upload "2.txt" -> Console prints contents of "1.txt"

3) Upload "3.txt" -> Console prints contents of "2.txt"

...

```js
function readData(){
  var fileholder = document.querySelector('#knotFiles');
  var content = 'Empty';
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event){
    content = event.target.result;
  }
  fileholder.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
    var files = fileholder.files;
    reader.readAsText(files[0]);
    console.log(content);
  }, false);
  return content;
};

readData();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="" />
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <input type="file" id="knotFiles" multiple>
    </div>
    <script src="knot.js">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am new to javascript and web development in general, so I apologize if this is a simple question. Thank you!

Comment: move `console.log(content);` into `reader.onload` function as this event will fire when *the reading operation is successfully completed.*

Comment: When I do this, it shows me that the "onload" does not get called when I first upload a file; only when I upload a second, differently-named file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`render.onload` is a `async` function In sort `content = event.target.result;` will execute at the end so put `console.log(content);` inside `render.onload` for latest changes in `content` data

```
function readData(){
  var fileholder = document.querySelector('#knotFiles');
  var content = 'Empty';
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event){
    content = event.target.result;
    console.log(content);
  }
  fileholder.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
    var files = fileholder.files;
    reader.readAsText(files[0]);

  }, false);
  return content;
};

readData();
```

Comment: Thank you, do you know any resources that will prevent me from making similar mistakes in the future?

Comment: your brain, and stackoverflow ;) And maybe sites like [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)....

Answer (score 0):

The `FileReader()` loads asynchronously - you are outputting the previous result because the variable `content` has not been updated yet before the event listener callback fires. Rewrite like this:

```
var fileholder = document.querySelector('#knotFiles');
fileholder.addEventListener("input", function(event) {
    readData();
}, false);

function readData(){  
    var content = '';
    var files = fileholder.files;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsText(files[0], "UTF-8"); // assumed this encoding
    reader.onload = function(event){
        content = event.target.result;
        console.log(content);
        return content;
    };
}
```